# How to override Datatables class?

Tags: css, datatables

I am using Datatables and I want to change color of cells. Problem is some td elements have "sorting-1" class attribute and it has style with "!important".

How can I override this background style?

Below td and class generated by Datatables;

```
.table.dataTable td.sorting_1, table.dataTable td.sorting_2, table.dataTable td.sorting_3, table.dataTable th.sorting_1, table.dataTable th.sorting_2, table.dataTable th.sorting_3{
    background:#fbfcfd! important;
}



<td class="sorting_1">sample text</td>
```

Comment: use  td.sorting_1{ background:#fbfcfd! important;} It will be useful

Comment: @priya_singh I added full class name. This is what I see when I inspect with chrome.